# How to find limits for $\theta$ for Gaussian Integrals

Tags: fake-proofs, gaussian-integral

I'm an engineering student who's been tasked with a maths problem slightly outside my field of study. It involves the evaluating the Gaussian integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$$

After doing some research online (because the lectures sure as hell didn't prepare us for this), I now know that this can be re-expressed as

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dx dy$$

such that $y=x$, but when converting from rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates I'm confused as to why the limits for $\theta$ are $0$ and $2\pi$. I tried proving this using L'Hopital's rule as follows:

Since $\theta = \tan^{-1} (y/x)$ and $y=x$, $\theta = \tan^{-1} (x/x)$. When evaluating the limit $x \rightarrow \infty$, we notice that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \tan^{-1} \bigg(\frac{x}{x}\bigg) = \tan^{-1} \bigg(\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{x} \bigg)$$

Using L'Hopital's rule, the limit equals $1/1$, which is obviously $1$. Ergo, the upper limit is $\tan^{-1}(1) = \pi/4$. Similarly, an identical approach can be used to (quote fingers) "demonstrate" (unquote fingers) that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \tan^{-1} \bigg(\frac{x}{x}\bigg) = \pi/4$$

Therefore, the limits for $\theta$ are the same, meaning that the integral equals $0$. A visual inspection of $e^{-x^2}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ shows this is wrong.

Please help.

EDIT: I now know why my usage of L'Hoptial's rule deosn't work. It's because I'm treating $y = e^{-x^2}$, which contradicts my definition of $y = x$.

Comment: The original integral is *not* equal to the second integral, though it is related to it -- your text implies equality, but perhaps that's not what you meant. (Second integral has a typo; is missing a dy)

Comment: I don't know why you're trying to use L'Hopital's rule and inverse tangents when switching to polar coordinates. It's much simpler than all that: the second integral over x and y is over the entire Cartesian plane, and so the integral in polar coordinates must also be over the entire polar plane. The limits on the radius and theta are just the limits the correspond to everything in the polar plane.

Comment: @jwimberley Fixed. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: @jwimberley surely $\theta$ only goes from $0$ to $\pi/2$ just by visual inspection of plotting the integrand with a domain of $[0, \infty)$; wouldn't it?

Comment: That's not the domain you wrote in your second integral, which, as written, is over the domain $[-\infty,\infty]$ for both x and y. There are two ways of solving the problem; one in which you relate the integral value $I$ to the second integral in your problem, which is over all four quadrants, and one which you relate it to an integral in just one quadrant, which is what the accepted answer does. The former, which is what whatever source you were consulting originally does, relies on the integrand being even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your double integral has some missing parts. Let $$I= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx $$

We know that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx =\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y^2} dy $$

Therefore we have $$ I^2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y^2} dy= \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dydx$$

Note that the region of integration is the first quadrant, which in polar form is $$ 0<\theta <\pi/2$$ and $$0< r <\infty$$

Solving for $I$ is straight forward because you can evaluate the integral in polar coordinates.

Comment: Wouldn't the domain for $\theta$ be $[0, \pi/2]$, not $[0, \pi/4]$? I think you may have confused $\pi$ with $\tau$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have changed the angle to $\pi /2$,  Thanks