# Why $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y^2} dy= \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dydx$?

Tags: integration

I was reading about evaluating Gaussian Integral using polar coordinates [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200549/how-to-find-limits-for-theta-for-gaussian-integrals). But I don't understand the following step,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y^2} dy= \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dydx$$Can you please elaborate on how we can combine the two integrals to get this double integral? ( I don't know which rule is used here).

Comment: $c\int f(x)\;dx = \int c\ f(x)\; dx$

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks for the help! I didn't notice that $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$ is independant of $y$ and we can treat it as a constant. It is clear now.